# Google charts tooltip on legend hover

Tags: event-handling, google-visualization, legend

I am using google charts.

I am trying to show multiple tooltips on legend hover on line and bar charts.

I am successful in showing multiple tooltips on legends but they are working on click and not working on hover.

This is the code to show multiple tooltip on legend click.

```
                   var options = {
                        curveType: 'function',
                        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                         selectionMode: 'multiple',
                         tooltip: { trigger: 'both' },
                         aggregationTarget: 'none',                        
                    };

                    var chart = new   google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                    chart.draw(data, options); 

                    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function(entry) {                 
                        chart.setSelection([ {column: entry.column} ]);      
                    });
                    
                    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', function(entry) {
                        chart.setSelection([]);
                    });
```

So how could I show the tooltip on legend hover?